# Can I pass between scriptlet and JSTL to escape XML?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, xss

I have a JSP scriptlet that takes GET parameters that must be XML-escaped to prevent XSS vulnerabilities.  Since Java doesn't have built-in XSS escaping functions, I'm trying to pass to JSTL's `fn:escapeXml()` and back to a scriptlet, like so:

```
<%@ (import fn taglib) %>
<%
String var1 = request.getParameter("input");
request.setAttribute("var1",var1);
%>
<c:set var="var1" scope="request" value="${fn:escapeXml(var1)}" />
<%
var1 = request.getAttribute("var1");
%>
```

When I try this, the server returns the ever-helpful "500: Internal Server Error."  Before I spend my day troubleshooting that, I thought I'd ask the experts: *Should* this work?  Is there an obvious error in the code I've presented, or should I look elsewhere for the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Throw the scriptlet code away and be happy...

Comment: You need to escape XML to prevent XSS only when you output something in your browser. If your `var1` variable has some HTML but you use it only in Java code without printing to JSP you do not need to escape XML there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, the approach presented should work.  The error is that the variables don't retain their type while being passed through JSTL.  Casting them back to `String` fixes the problem:

```
<%@ (import fn taglib) %>
<%
String var1 = request.getParameter("input");
request.setAttribute("var1",var1);
%>
<c:set var="var1" scope="request" value="${fn:escapeXml(var1)}" />
<%
var1 = (String)request.getAttribute("var1");
%>
```